# What is the difference between a SPF include: and a:?

Tags: email, spam-prevention, spf

I have read through the documentation but the difference is still not very clear to me.

My understanding is:
1) include: will allow the IPs listed for the specified domain, and also any additional domains listed in that domain's own SPF records

2) a: simply allows IPs listed for the specified domain

Is that correct?

Comment: It's important to note that `include`d records do not cause back doors - if you have a `-all` default action but an included domain uses `?all`, it will not override your own setting.

Answer (score 19):

Another try at an answer for anyone else trying to put this together, and based on the syntax doc that OP is probably referring to, the [open-spf.org "SPF Record Syntax" page](http://www.open-spf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax/).

> Note: Previously this document lived at `http://www.open-spf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax/`, but that domain seems to have gone offline permanently in 2009. More details on the history and missing domain can be found [here](https://www.getmailbird.com/what-spf-resources-are-available-now-that-openspf-org-is-gone/).

My answer is that yes, you seem to have it in mind.

- a: Test the IP for a match in the A records for the domain.
- include: Fetch the entire SPF record for the domain, evaluate IP against it, and if a PASS is found then that PASS becomes the result of the whole SPF test. If no PASS is found then it's not a fail, but your original/top-level SPF test continues (probably to the -all/~all/?all phase).

Reasons to use "a":

- Because it's more predictable and straightforward.
- Because you haven't set up SPF on the relevant domains.
- Because you don't control those domains and the SPF isn't what you'd want (specifically if it's too lenient in accepting other servers that aren't in it's A records)

Reasons to use "include":

- Because you already trust the SPF of the domain.
- Because the SPF of the domain is complex, and you want to have a single source of truth for don't-repeat-yourself reasons.

Happy to be corrected!

Comment: Remember, **a:** tests for a match in the A _or AAAA_ records

Comment: If you host a lot of websites but don't necessarily host their DNS, using an `include:` allows you to make future changes to the SPF records without making direct DNS changes to the domains that include yours.

Answer (score 7):

1) include:*other-domain.com* just includes SPF records from *other-domain.com*.
If SPF entries of *other-domain.com* allows some ip's (for example have an ip4: or a: entry), then those ip will be also be allowed.

2) true